# Exclude objects on Haystack search without the need of update_index

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I need Haystack search to exclude some objects with value `published=False`, the way I've managed it so far is by adding an `exclude(published=True)` as following:

```
class MymodelIndex(indexes.RealTimeSearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Mymodel.objects.all().exclude(published=False)
```

It works as expected, the problem is that I need to `./manage.py rebuild_index` everytime a new object is added to the database which makes it terrible.

How can I make it without the need to run anything else ?

Notes:

Indexes on Haystack work for many models, so something like this:

```
search = (
    SearchQuerySet().filter(content=term)
)
```

returns many kinds of objects and not just one model.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you need to rebuild the index every time a new object is added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SI Eric, I was able to find an answer, it's also kinda hacky but it works.

```
search = (
    SearchQuerySet().filter(content=term)
)

search_list = search[:]
unpublished_Mymodels = Mymodel.objects.filter(published=False)

for match in search_list:
    try:
        if match.model_name == 'Mymodel':
            if match._get_object() in unpublished_Mymodels:
                search_list.remove(match)
    except:
        pass

search = search_list
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently had to do something similar to this and it was a pain in the arse.  I could not find any other way to do this.

First off to address the issue of Haystack working on many models and so filter returns all matches:

Haystack handles model filtering behind the scenes using a property it indexes called django_ct, which equals the app name and model name.  In my particular case it looked something like `django_ct='books.Title'`.

You could try filtering by doing

```
SearchQuerySet.filter(content=term, django_ct='app.Model')
```

But I don't know if it will work that way.  In my particular case I had to do a raw search anyway, so I was able to add the filtering directly to that:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet()
sqs = sqs.raw_search(u'(title:(%s)^500 OR author:"%s"^400 OR "%s"~2 OR (%s)) AND (django_ct:books.Title)' % term)
```

Regardless of how you get it, after you get your `SearchQuerySet` that you want to do additional filtering on without updating the index, you have to do it with your own code.

```
# each item in a queryset has a pk property to the model instance it references
pks = [item.pk for item in list(sqs)] # have to wrap sqs in a list otherwise it causes problems

# use those pks to create a standard django queryset object
results = Model.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)

# Now you can do any additional filtering like normal
results = results.exclude(published=False)
```

Of course you can combine the last two queries, I just split them out to be explicit.

It's not that much code, but it took me a long while to get it working for various reasons.  Hopefully it helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I still think is overkill, there must be a way to just exclude objects.

Comment: I would hope there is, I just had no success in finding one.  The SearchQuerySet object mimics some functionality of the Django QuerySet object, but it is limited in what it can do.

Answer (score 2):

Since haystack 2.4.0 you can raise `haystack.exceptions.SkipDocument` to skip individual records which are easily excluded using `index_queryset`

https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/releases/tag/v2.4.0

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to filter by an object in Haystack. I had a vary similar issue to above and came across the `models` method in the Haystack `SearchQuerySet` API docs.

From Haystack (http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#models)

`SearchQuerySet.models(self, *models)`

Accepts an arbitrary number of Model classes to include in the search. This will narrow the search results to only include results from the models specified.

Example:

`SearchQuerySet().filter(content='foo').models(BlogEntry, Comment)`

So from here you can filter by content within the object as needed.